# javascript updating hidden value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function:

```
function add() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "add.php",
        async: "false", // Tried both- async: "false/true"
        data: {
            name: 'Test',
        },
        success: function(data) {
            document.getElementById('id').value = data;
            id = document.getElementById('id').value;
            alert(id); // alerts here proper value
        }
    });

}

function testMyFunction() {
    add();

    // 'id' was set in add function.
    id = document.getElementById('id').value;
    alert(id); // Here does not alert value but blank(no value)
    // This 'id' value is used at other place but here is issue. 
}
```

Calling testMyFunction() function gives above mentioned issue.

What could be a issue?

Comment: Would you please indent your code properly the next time?! The code style was horrible. Also, you do NOT want `async: false`. Just call your code asynchronously using a callback after the request has been successful.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, is telling someone that their post was horrible really the best way to welcome a first-time asker to the community?

Comment: True, could have been worded a bit nicer. On the other side, one should already write properly indented code in the first place.

Comment: Faced kinda same type of welcome in my case also in numerous occasions.

Comment: @LcSalazar, he did indeed, with an edit, after my comment.

Comment: What is the element you want to give it the value of data ?, is a div or input ?

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but `async` is a boolean, so strictly it should be `false` without quotes.

Answer (score 3):

$.ajax is an asynchronous call and it updates "id" field after if it is completed. Your code checks for its value in function testMyFunction() instantly after the invocation (and before success: function(data) is invoked).

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is an *asynchronous* language. In a nutshell, this means that your code should **NEVER** block: functions should either complete immediately or get called later, i.e. after some input/output operation is complete (e.g. AJAX request).

**Edited:** BTW, your code does not work because even with `async: false` the `success` function is called in the *event loop*, thus this can occur even after the code that follows synchronous AJAX. If you use `async: true`, the AJAX will block, but the `success` function will be called **asynchronously** in any case.
So to handle data synchronously, you have to work not with `success` function, but rather with an object that is returned by `$.ajax()` call:

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    url: "add.php",
    data: {
        name: 'Test',
    },
});
alert(xhr.responseText); // Alerts result
```

Thus, you should **never** use `async: false`. Instead, better refactor your code to be like this:

```
function add(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "add.php",
        data: {
            name: 'Test',
        },
        success: callback
    });
}

function testMyFunction() {
    add(function(data) {
        // This closure will be called AFTER the request is complete.
        document.getElementById('id').value = data;
        alert(data); // Alerts proper value.
    });
}
```

Basically, this pseudo-code is WRONG:

```
result1 = action1();
result2 = action2(result1);
result3 = action3(result2);
```

...and should be written like this:

```
action1(function(result1) {
    action2(result1, function(result2) {
        alert(action3(result2));
    });
});
```

Comment: Never say never. ;) Anyway, do you have an idea why calling it synchronously doesn't work in OP's case?